# Python: ctypes invoking callback method from another thread

Tags: python, c++, multithreading, ctypes

I have a C library which takes a callback and invokes it in another thread of it own.

```
from ctypes import *

class MyCLibrary:
    def __init__(self):
        self.lib_ = cdll.LoadLibrary("mycdll")

    def Setcallback(self, callback):
        CallbackT = CFUNCTYPE(None, c_wchar_p)
        self.hModule_.IMcCSPSDK_SetLogger(CallbackT(callback))

    lib = MyCLibrary()

def mycallback(param1):
    print param1
lib.SetCallback(mycallback)
lib.Init()
raw_input()
```

while main thread wait on raw_input(), some thread from mycdll.dll calls the callback, which crashes with access violation. Violations happend in mycdll.dll at callsite where it attempts to invoke callback, the python provided function is not null but some junk. The callback works correctly if called from main thread. any clues?

Comment: Store a reference to `CallbackT(callback)` for as long as the callback may be called. There's a bolded, boxed note about this in the docs, section [15.17.1.17. Callback functions](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes#callback-functions).

Comment: That is relevant pointer, I am already sounding like kids who rush to SO rather than read docs. Python is not my primary skill so I may be like those kids after all. Below worked for me `self.writeLog = WriteLogT(writeLog)
self.hModule_.IMcCSPSDK_SetLogger(self.writeLog)` Thanks for you help.